# Monotone-increasing Version Number based on Mercurial Commits

Tags: mercurial, versioning

When I was using subversion for the code for an application, I could append a period and the result of `svnversion` to the version number to create a unique and monotone-increasing version number and also be guaranteed that any check-out of the same revision of the code would generate the same version number.

In Mercurial, because revision numbers are not necessarily consistent across clones, the local revision number is not suitable.  The hash is appropriately unique and consistent, but does not create a number that is monotone-increasing.  How can I generate a suitable number to append to the version number based on the Mercurial repository commits?

*edit:*  I have an application that has automatic update checking that is dependent on a version number that is a chain of period-separated whole numbers to determine whether or not a version is newer or not.  It has become common that in the time between releases, I have some users trying out test builds.  Often, these builds solve an issue the tester was having, so the tester stops using the released version and switches to the test build.  My original goals in adding the additional component to the version number were to:

- ensure that when the release came, those using the test build were automatically presented with the update as well
- be able to easily tell if a tester was using the most recent test build

For example, the 0.5.0 release had version number 0.5.0.410; before 0.5.1 was released, there were test builds with version numbers 0.5.1.411, 0.5.1.420, and 0.5.1.421; then, the 0.5.1 release had version number 0.5.1.423.

Comment: its not clear why you think you need this.

Comment: @jk I've added more explanation--does that help?

Comment: I'm thinking of switching from SVN to Hg and I have the same problem - auto-updates based on the monotone increasing build number.

Comment: @Igor:  You can see what I've ended up doing in my comment on my answer, below.  I think the benefits of hg overall and specifically in easier merging far outweigh the downside of having to find a new way to construct version numbers for auto-updating.

Comment: @Isaac, I'm still hoping Hg's revision numbering (http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RevisionNumber) will do the trick for me. Since I'm the only developer in the "team", I can designate a certain repository to be the official release repo and use the numbering from there.

Comment: @Igor: It may well work for you then.  For me, even though I'm the sole developer on the project that I initially used this for, the only repo I would have used as the "official" repo was a remote copy that was almost never up-to-date at build time.  (Secondarily, the revision numbers in the official repo won't necessarily match those in the development repos, particularly with branching/merging going on, which can make it a bit harder to take that revision number and turn it back into a copy of the code from that time that can be built and debugged.)

Comment: @Isaac I guess I'll have to try it out. Keeping the same numbering scheme (sequential, increased by 1) is important for me because I don't want to confuse users too much with random numbering.

Comment: @Igor:  That's why I use *major.minor.build.build* — the first two parts, which a normal user might actually pay attention to, are not based on the build, but the third and fourth, which still affect auto-updating (and are actually displayed in fewer places) are based on the build.

Comment: @Isaac early on I decided to hide all that version numbering from users and only show them the build number, it was too much hassle to maintain and frankly I don't think the users really cared if it was 2.1.33.1234 or 2.2.33.1234. The build number is also displayed in the main form's title, that's why it's so important in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still in need of something to try to maintain ordering and matching of various development builds, I first tried using the unix timestamp of the last commit:

```
REV=$(hg tip --template '{date|hgdate}' | cut -f1 -d' ')
```

This, however, is annoyingly long (10 digits).  (And, of course, it's not guaranteed to be unique, but on a project where I'm the only developer, the probability of two commits in the same second is essentially 0; in fact, the probability of two commits within 1 minute of each other is essentially 0.)

Since the "base" version number (the part to which this revision number is appended) only changes immediately after a tagged release, what I've ended up using is the number of minutes between the tip and the latest tagged ancestor:

```
HG_LAST_TAG_TIMESTAMP=$(hg log -r "$(hg log -r '.' --template '{latesttag}')" --template "{date|hgdate}\n" | cut -f1 -d' ')
HG_TIP_TIMESTAMP=$(hg log -r '.' --template "{date|hgdate}\n" | cut -f1 -d' ')
REV=$(( ($HG_TIP_TIMESTAMP - $HG_LAST_TAG_TIMESTAMP) / 60 ))
```

(*edit*: using `tip` was a mistake, as it refers to the latest commit to any branch; using `log -r '.'` refers to the revision on which the working copy is based.)

Comment: For anyone looking at this in the future (and I didn't want to bump the question, so I'm not editing it), I've switched to (1) using Python to access the mercurial information, (2) using version.major.minor.days.minutes (e.g. 0.7.0.196.72136) where days is a 3-digit number of days since the last release and minutes is a 5-digit number of minutes since the last release (not counting the whole days), and (3) automatically tagging the revision in the local repo when assembling a development test-build that will go out to others.  It's not perfect, but it fits my needs.

Comment: Note: it is traditional for environment variables to be upper-case, and local variables to be lower-case.

Answer (score 6):

As [@Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486214/monotone-increasing-version-number-based-on-mercurial-commits/2486253#2486253) said, you can't expect any comparison between version numbers across clones to be of any value. However, if you base your application around a single repository and always push back to that central repository from any clones then you could rely on that single central version number as long as you stuck to a single branch.

Essentially, if you use Mercurial in a way that mimics Subversion, i.e. with a single central repository, you can use version number as a marker on your application builds.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 thanks for your answer.

While I do have a central repo to which I push all changes, it's out-of-order to try to use it to get a build number because at build time, the current revision hasn't been pushed.

More importantly, as you said, then I'd just be mimicking Subversion, which is probably not making good use of Mercurial.

Comment: You can still use all the power of Mercurial, but you just make it work to a workflow that suits your needs. In your case you essentially want your clones to *know* about versions built on other clones. Using a central repository for "official" releases seems like a reasonable way forward.

Answer (score 5):

This is how Fog Creek does the build versioning using Mercurial + some other suggestions: https://web.archive.org/web/20130501070904/http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/best-practice-generating-build-numbers

Answer (score 4):

You've pretty much hit the nail on the head.  Using *any* monotonically-increasing local revision number can conflict with the distributed nature.  There is no elegant way around this fundamental design decision.

Comment: ... revision numbers are local by definition as they are inferred from the development history.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is pretty much what I expected, but I was hoping I'd missed something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `hg log -r 'ancestors(.)'` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797840/mercurial-use-hg-log-to-view-all-ancestors/4797997#4797997) in conjunction with a simple `--template` and `wc -w` to [count the amount of ancestors](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/rev/8b6e8611982a) that a given changeset has.

This number is fixed for a given changeset as it depends on the changeset's history. It doesn't depend on the order changesets arrived in the repo. That is, it is global (unlike Mercurial's local revision numbers) as a given changeset always carries with it the full history of all its ancestors. However, it is a nicer and more useful numeric value to a user than the node ID hash. Within a given branch it allows to compare and sort the amount of ancestors.

You do still have to keep track of branches, if you use them, but this number is less of a hassle to preserve and communicate than the local revision number.

Other than the branches I believe this is close to the monotonically increasing revision number that you want. It might be useful to include a branch name along with the amount of ancestors to avoid duplicates across different branches.

---

Here's the changeset I linked above:

> #### mak.sh: in revision ID string include amount of ancestors
>
> This number is both fixed for a given changeset whereever it goes and
> also allows to compare two numbers, assuming they're on the same
> branch, to one another to figure out which one is "later" or more
> advanced, so to say.

```
-  [ -z "$build_revision_id" ] && build_revision_id="hg $(hg id -i)"
+  [ -z "$build_revision_id" ] \
+    && build_revision_id="hg $(hg id -i) ($( \
+      hg log -r 'ancestors(.)' --template '1 ' | wc -w) ancestors)"
```