# Mercurial - use hg log to view all ancestors

Tags: mercurial

Given changesets

```
a
--b
----c
------d
--------e
```

How can I get a listing of all changesets that come before d.  Ie: how can you use hg log to return a-b-c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `hg log -r :d` (but it will also display d).

Comment: That works for a linear history, but not for anything more complex. That shows all revisions numerically lower than or equal to d, but that will includes changes on other branches that haven't been merged into d.

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
hg log -r "ancestors(d)"
```

This requires the revsets feature in Mercurial 1.7 and later.  See `hg help revsets` for some great fun.

Comment: I used this in conjunction with a simple `--template` and `wc -w` to [count the amount of ancestors](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/rev/8b6e8611982a) that a given changeset has. This is global (unlike Mercurial's local revision numbers) as a given changeset always carries with it the full history of all its ancestors. However, it is a nicer and more useful numeric value to a user than the node ID hash. Within a given branch it allows to compare and sort the amount of ancestors.

Answer (score 3):

```
hg log -r d::a
```

or

```
hg log -r a::d
```

This will require a reasonably recent (I believe 1.6 or later) version of Mercurial to work.