# Mercurial - use hg log to view all descendants

Tags: mercurial

To view all ancestors of a changeset [you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797840/mercurial-use-hg-log-to-view-all-ancestors/4798003#4798003) `hg log -r :xyz`.  How can you view all descendants of a changeset?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use newer mercurial you can use `hg log -r 'descendants(xyz)'` or `hg log -r xyz::`.

Comment: This is only for simple liniar cases. `xyz:` shows changes whose number is greater or equal to xyz's number.

Comment: What would qualify as a non simple case?

Comment: Suppose xyz is on branch A, you update to branch B, make a commit (abc), `hg log -r xyz:` shows abc whether or not abc is an actual descendant of xyz (perhaps they share an older common ancestor). `hg log -r xyz::.` only shows abc if it is a true descendant.

Answer (score 2):

From the console, I am not sure. However if I need to do this I start:

```
hg serve
```

and then view the graph that Mercurial will generate in a browser.