# Total Count of Change Sets for Mercurial and Git

Tags: git, mercurial

Is it possible to count the number of Mercurial/Git changesets (commits) with a simple command line with arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `git`:

```
git log --pretty=oneline | wc -l
```

will give you the count of all commits on the current branch back to the original commit.

To get the count of all commits on all branches:

```
git log --pretty=oneline --all | wc -l
```

Answer (score 14):

For mercurial just check the numeric revision id of 'tip' (defined as the highest numbered revision):

```
$ hg id --num --rev tip
97
```

Comment: That's right.  If you want a shellish way to add 1 you'd do `$((1 + $(hg id --num --rev tip)))`

Comment: That result is not necessarily true. Obsolete (thus extinct) changesets count towards that number. The real number of commits is thus equal or smaller than the output of `hg id -n -rtip`. It's only guaranteed to be equal for a fresh clone.

Comment: @planetmaker: I used `hg log -r 'ancestors(.)'` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797840/mercurial-use-hg-log-to-view-all-ancestors/4797997#4797997) in conjunction with a simple `--template` and `wc -w` to [count the amount of ancestors](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/rev/8b6e8611982a) that a given changeset has. This number is fixed for a changeset as it depends on the changeset's history. Unlike the local revision number it counts only ancestors, not other heads. And it doesn't depend on the order changesets arrived in the repo.

Answer (score 5):

I would take a look at [churn extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChurnExtension) shipped with Mercurial. It lets you count the number of changesets per developer or per time period. It looks like this:

```
$ hg churn -s -c -f "%Y-%m"
2005-05    208 *****************************                                    
2005-06    341 ***********************************************
2005-07    271 *************************************
...
```

If you just want to know the number of changesets matching a given [revision set](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets), then use `hg log` and `wc` like others have suggested:

```
$ hg log -r "user(geisler) and date('>2010')" --template x | wc -c
735
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my quick solution:

```
  hg log | grep changeset | wc -l
```

(Of course this only wokrs if nobody writes changeset in their commit messages, etc.)

---

Explanation:

`hg log` returns information in this format:

```
changeset:   232351:06d3053eg093
branch:      default/XXXXXX
bookmark:    hg
tag:         tip
user:        User
date:        Thu Feb 20 10:22:30 2020 +0100
summary:     XXXXXX: cleanup in test
```

Greping only one of the lines and then counting the lines gives you the count.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this question is really old, but here's a more git-native way to get the commit count for git.  I'm using git 2.15 currently, but I don't know how long this has been around.

```
git rev-list --all --count
```

for a total across all branches, or

```
git rev-list HEAD --count
```

for ancestors of HEAD (or any other changeset).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following scriptlet to count the amount of hg ancestors that a specific revision has:

```
hg log -r 'ancestors(.)' --template '1' \
 | wc --bytes
```

Added in https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/rev/8b6e8611982a with this message:

> mak.sh: in revision ID string include amount of ancestors
>
> This number is both fixed for a given changeset whereever
> it goes and also allows to compare two numbers, assuming
> they're on the same branch, to one another to figure out
> which one is "later" or more advanced, so to say.

Although that exact command is from https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/rev/6cbc8bdbb764

This counts the amount of all ancestor changesets in the history up to and including the one listed. (That's the dot `.` for current working directory parent in the example, you can use another revision specification however.) That means it doesn't matter what other branches may exist in the same repo, unlike the numeric local revision ID.